# Error adding Office 365 Unified API (preview) to Azure AD

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, outlook-restapi

When trying to add permissions to the "Office 365 Unified API (preview)" in my Azure AD management portal and then save I always get the error:

"Could not update the configuration for app ''" with the following details:

"Please try again. If the problem persists, contact support."

I tried for 2 days and it doesn't work. I cannot contact support since I am using a Azure trial to test this software. What is going on ? Any ideas ? I really want to test this software for its potential.

The same for the "Office 365 Management API" permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you get a correlation id? what happens if you refresh the page?

Comment: After a refresh the changes seem to be there. I didn't get a correlationID, also not all fields refresh properly but at least it should work now.
Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem.

1. After reload - not all fields loaded. To fix that - we click on Azure logo. That is not how it should work!
2. The same problem with adding "Office 365 Unified API (preview)". That is big issue. After saving permissions, I am not able to change anything, as always get the same error: Could not update the configuration for app. Please try again. If the problem persists, contact support.

What is support contact?